# reacquiring lock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Im declaring a variable of type Condition:

```
private Condition waitingCond;
```

Then, in the constructor of `Bridge` I declare a condition variable associated to the same variable:

```
waitingCond = lock.NewCondition();
```

Then in a blocking method, I have this:

```
public void getIn(int direction) throws InterruptedException{
    lock.lock(); 
    try{
        if(direction == Car.DIR_NORTH){
            while((nSudWaiting>0)) 
            waitingCond.await(); 
            nNordWaiting++;  
            //...............
        } else {
            //............
        } waitingCond.signal();
    }
    finally{ 
        lock.unlock() 
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Am I right in saying that here, the method await implies releasing the lock? 
   `waitingCond.await(); // waiting release lock`
2. If what I stated above is correct, does the following statement enable the lock again (the thread holds the lock)?

   `waitingCond.await(); // waiting release lock`
   `nNordWaiting++;  // getting back the lock`

What I'd like to understand is: any kind of statement following `waitingCond.await();` can reacquire the lock?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Was the answer below helpful? If so, you should accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition%28%29) on Lock.newCondition:

> A call to Condition.await() will atomically release the lock before waiting and re-acquire the lock before the wait returns.

This means that when await() is called, the lock is released, but once your code continues past await, the lock is re-acquired automatically.

The documentation for [await](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await%28%29) elaborates (emphasis mine):

> **The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released** and the
>   current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and
>   lies dormant until one of four things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the signal() method for this Condition and
>     the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened; or
> - Some other thread invokes the signalAll() method for this
>     Condition; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread, and
>     interruption of thread suspension is supported; or
> - A "spurious wakeup"
>     occurs.
>
> In all cases, **before this method can return the current thread
>   must re-acquire the lock associated with this condition. When the
>   thread returns it is guaranteed to hold this lock.**

Comment: So what I wrote is correct? waitingCond.await(); // waiting release lock
 nNordWaiting++;  // getting back the lock

Comment: @user962800 Yes.  (Well, to be pedantic and overly literal no -- `nNordWaiting++` does not actually "get back the lock".  It's already been re-acquired by that point.  So a more accurate comment may be "have reacquired the lock", and really the re-acquiring happens before that statement.)